# can iverilog report setup-time violations in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I use

```
specify 
  $setup(d,posedge clk, 5);
endspecify
```

to give an setup time for dff. However, when clk rises just 2 units of time after d changes, there is not setup time violation issued. I use iverilog to simulate.

How can I see such violations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will not see violations.  I just downloaded what I think is the latest (`verilog-0.9.7.tar.gz`), and I saw this in the `README.txt` file:

> - Specify blocks are parsed but ignored in general.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I saw they had one directive when you compile, -gspecify. I guess they haven't got time to implement it out yet. Is there any other free tools they can do timing analysis?